# batch insert with mysql default value

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a(
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'none',
   `state` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
   `createtime` datetime(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO table_a(`name`, `state`, `createtime`) VALUES
('aaa', `DEFAULT_VALUE`, '2020-01-09 00:00:00'),
(`DEFAULT_VALUE`, 1, `DEFAULT_VALUE`)
```

For each `DEFAULT_VALUE` I want to write something like `IfNull(xx, yy)`, only that I'm writing a batch insert sql template so I don't know exactly what default value is in the table create statement, so I can't write `IfNull(xx, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3))` but something more general like `IfNull(xx, 'DEFAULT_VALUE_IN_TABLE_DECLARATION')`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this other than perhaps a trigger.  As you already probably know, the typical use case of default values are for when a column is explicitly omitted in an insert.  In that case, MySQL would use the backup default value.  Any reason why you can't just hard code the default values?

Comment: You may use ``ifnull(@value, DEFAULT(`fieldname`))`` for fields where default value is literal (`name`, `state`). You cannot use this construction for auto-utilized datetime because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a function, not literal.